# Regex to pull data from strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a column with random strings but I have to pull data from the string. A number with length 8 or greater.

These are the two strings:

```
x = "CHARGES*198953* 47694000 Brown * TFR"

y = "47694000 Koistin *    192333*UNSWORTH R* TFR"
```

---

Regex that work for `y` but not for `x`:

```
x1 = re.findall(r'^[1-9][0-9]{2,}',y)
```

I get nothing for x.

Comment: Well, your regexp demands that the string starts with one of the characters 1-9, and x starts with a C.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
x1 = re.findall(r'\d{7}\d+', x)
```

Result:

```
['47694000']
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've updated that. Thanks

Comment: You can make it more concise with `r'\d{7,}'`